# Question concerning the existence of natural transformations of two conjugate functors of groups regarded as categories.

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory, natural-transformations

I am reading and learning some basic category theory. I found the following problem on *Categories for the Working Mathematician* (I understand that it may not be the best learning source for a beginner, but the way Lane defines everything is so fascinating):

> If $C, B$ are two groups regarded as categories with one object each and $S, T$ are functors, show that there exists a natural transformation if and only if $S$ and $T$ are conjugate; i.e., there exists $h\in B$ with $Tg=h(Sg)h^{-1}$ for all $g\in C$.

Here is the "if" part. Since $Tg=h(Sg)h^{-1}$, we have $T(g)\circ h=h\circ S(g)$. Therefore $h$ defines a natural transformation. However, I am not quite sure what the components of this natural transformation are. Since $h$ is an element in $B$, we can make $h$ be a component at $B$. **But how can we define the component at $C$ by $h$?**

I am even more confused when I get to the only if part. Suppose the following diagram commutes,

[image]

We have $T(\tau_C\circ g)=\tau_B\circ S(g)$ for all $g$ in $C$ (I know this is incorrect because the aimed "shape" is $T(g)\circ T(\tau_C)=\tau_B\circ S(g)$, so please correct my seriously false understanding). How can we go from this equation to the conjugacy?

Thanks in advance. I couldn't find a similar question on MathSE but please let me know if this post is a duplicate.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1730468/245577) and the ones linked to it might help.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Thank you, but it seems that my question is way more basic than the question in the link you provided.

Comment: Maybe, but some of the answers cover your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that the natural transformation $\tau:S\to T$ is indexed by the objects of the category $C$.
Let $X$ denote the only object of $C$.
Then for every morphism $g:X\to X$ in $C$ we have a commutative square$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S(X)@>\tau_X>>T(X)\\
@VS(g)VV@VVT(g)V\\
S(X)@>>\tau_X>T(X)
\end{CD}
where $\tau_X$ is the only component of $\tau$.
If $Y$ is the only object of $D$, then $Y=S(X)=T(X)$ and putting $h=\tau_X$ the previous diagram become:
\begin{CD}
Y@>h>>Y\\
@VS(g)VV@VVT(g)V\\
Y@>>h>Y
\end{CD}
that's $S(g)h=hT(g)$.

In other words, the natural transformation $\tau$ has one component only (because the category $C$ as one object only) and this component is the morphism $h$ which satisfy $S(g)h=hT(g)$.

Comment: Great answer. So instead of seeing the category $C$ as whole, we actually "expand" the category $C$ and then apply the funtors to get the natural transformation. Is that correct?

Comment: Think the group $C$ as a category with one object, say $X$; the elements $g$ of the group are morphisms $g:X\to X$.